# How to limit the number of running tasks on akka scheduler?

Tags: java, playframework, akka, playframework-2.5

I have an application in Java Play Framework and the user can run multiple tasks at the same time and it can take a long time to finish. I thought that I could used the `actorSystem.scheduler()` in order to do that. However, I've made a few tests and found out that the user can run up to 4 tasks at the same time otherwise the tasks would be taking more resources than my server could provide. So Is there a way to limit the number of tasks running at the same time on the Akka scheduler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to globally limit the concurrent tasks, you could set the akka max pool size to that number. Information about configuration is available here: https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaAkka

Specifically, there is a setting:

```
akka.actor.default-dispatcher.fork-join-executor.pool-size-max = 64
```

which you can set to the maximum number of tasks you want to run concurrently. This is the number of threads that will be used.

Comment: Let's say that I have placed a limit on 10 tasks and my user sends another task, what would happen to this new task? Akka would place it into a queue or something similar? And I guess that changing the pool size it will change way more than the number of concurrent tasks on the scheduler but also how play deals with the requests, am I right?

Comment: Yes, Akka uses the concept of Mailboxes which can be durable (the default is not): http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/mailboxes.html. The default is an Unbounded in-memory mailbox, but there are durable mailboxes such as those listed on this page: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/modules/durable-mailbox.html

Comment: Just found out that I can create a new dispatcher only to be used on this feature so my configuration won't affect the other stuff that uses the default-dispatcher. Thanks a lot @Jamie.

Answer (score 0):

use a pool (which can be a blockingLinkQueue) to store the scheduler object.

when the user comes, try to get an instance from the pool, otherwise wait. do so 2 control the max scheduler u will use in ur system.